# Ruby on rails : Avoiding inputs from user and doing a dry updation on models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have made one update method inside Active record like this :-

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def status_update(new_status)
    return unless Helper.confirm_from_user?(new_status) # take input from user 
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      ## update logic
    end
  end
end

class Helper
  def self.confirm_from_user? value
    puts "Hi , Please check the value again #{value} "
    puts "Press y if you want to update"
    gets.chomp == "y" ? true : false
  end
end
```

If i have to update the status of my model . Then it will ask for conformation .

I am facing this problem that sometimes i have to do 1000 or more status updates for a model .

```
Car.where(:id => 1..1000).each{|car| car.status_update("checked") } .
```

Here i have to enter yes for all 1000 .

Please provide some good solutions(avoid flags) so that i get to know how my entity will look after updating and then i can confirm the changes . I will need old values and new values for some log creation .

Comment: please provide also the purpoer for the mass update record from a console

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ - can't explain here . but have to do all the updates from console only

Comment: As for the logging of new and old values look at [`ActiveModel:Dirty`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Dirty). You can use things like `status_change` which will return [new_value,old_value]. But I agree with @МалъСкрылевъ what is the purpose of mass updating from the console where a rails user will not see the console.

Comment: @T.J. but which is the purpose?

Comment: user here is console user not rails ui

Comment: @T.J. but has he rails console?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the current object with `self`. Now all models include `ActiveModel`'s utilities, you can use them to inspect the state of the object as follows:

```
c = Car.create! name: "Car 123"
c.name # => "Car 123"
c.changes # => {}
c.name = "Car 124"
c.changed? # => true
c.changes # => {"name"=>["Car 123", "Car 124"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please keep the model, controller and view separated, model not wasted by the foreign code. The user request and confirmation is for the view part, or just absent. So use in model/controller codes like follows:

```
class ModelWithConfirmation < class ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :confirmed

   before_validation {|record| record.confirmed? }
end

class CustomerController
   def mass_update
      ModelWithConfirmation.all.update_all(name: params[:name], confirmed: params[:confirmed])
   end
end
```

Then [issue a request from console](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/back-to-basics-http-requests):

```
$ curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST \
       -d ' {"name":"Volodimir"}'  http://localhost:3000/customer/1/mass_update
```

Of course you need to setup the routes properly.

Or you just can update records with a single line from the `rails` or [pry](/questions/tagged/pry) console:

```
ModelWithConfirmation.all.update_all(name: "Volodimir")
Car.where(:id => 1..1000).update_all(status: 'checked')
```